# ADF: Access ResourceBundle value in Javascript

Tags: oracle-adf

I've a resource bundle in my JSFF page. How do I access the bundle KEY VALUE in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the value in a component like:

```
<af:outputText value="#{'YOUR RESOURCE BUNDLE VALUE'}"
```

Then, read the value from using a ADF client Listener.
More info on how you can use ADF Javascript API, here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/1-2011-javascript-302460.pdf

Comment: I've done the output text as well as input hidden and tried accessing with document.getElementById() and the adf PAGE api AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId. It returns null. Can you share the code snippet if you have accessed it.

Comment: your absolute ID is not your component id. Is a path to your component

Comment: How about document.getElementById